# React/Express.js: how to avoid multiple API calls

Tags: reactjs, api, express, wikipedia

Update:

I am trying to store the death count in a variable inside an array and increment the array with the death count. Only when the new variable is different from the last one in the array should I run a wiki api call.

Now my problem is that I can't populate the array with more than 1 variable. Anyone knows what's wrong with the code below?:

After the const data, I added this function:

```
  function countStats() {
  const counter = [];
  var deathCounter = data.deaths.value;
  counter.push(deathCounter);
  console.log(counter.length);
  return counter;
}

countStats();
```

it keeps returning length: 1 even after multiple calls to the wiki() function

I have a react app with an express.js server. I use wikijs on the server to make API calls to wikipedia. Everything works and I get the data I need from Wikipedia!

I will need at most 4 calls a day to the API to update Covid statistics for a country. Right now, when the react component mounts, there's a call to the express server which in turn will make an api call to wikipedia. That will trigger unnecessary calls if the app is used by hundreds or thousands of users.

How do I avoid the multiple calls? In other words, I want to somehow cache the results of the first 2 calls.

This is my Express.js. I am putting the result of the api call inside the object data:

```
wiki()
  .page("COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria")
  .then((page) => page.fullInfo())
  .then((info) => {
    (data.confirmed.value = info.general.confirmedCases),
      (data.recovered.value = info.general.recoveryCases),
      (data.deaths.value = info.general.deaths);

   });

const data = {
  confirmed: { value: 0 },
  deaths: { value: 0 },
  recovered: { value: 0 },
};

     app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
       res.json(data);
     });
```

And this is where I am calling the express.js route from in React:

```
 const url = "/api";

export const fetchData = async () => {
  }
  try {
    const {
      data: { confirmed, deaths, recovered },
    } = await axios.get(url)
    return { confirmed, deaths, recovered };
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

And finally in App.js I am calling the fetchData function above:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await fetchData();
    this.setState({ data });
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You already mentioned that you need to cache the result of the API call and update it periodically. What ideas have you thought of to approach that problem?

Comment: @jered I was actually thinking along the line of using a setIntervall to make the api call periodically (every 5 hours for instance). I haven't really written any code yet for the caching solution.

Comment: You’re already storing the results of the wiki call in `data`. So maybe try having your setInterval update that periodically?

Comment: please see my update above